# In statuses / user_timeline, I want to get my tweets (with retweets) by date range

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

In statuses / user_timeline, I want to get my tweets (with retweets) by date range

Parameters I want to specify

- From twitter user name
- Since (2019/08/25)
- Until (2019/09/01)

How do I get "since_id" and "max_id" for the period from August 25, 2019 to September 1, 2019?

---

**March 22, 2020. I have added the following code and explanation.**

I want to write as follows, but "since" cannot be specified. "until" cannot be specified more than 7 days ago

```
$request_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json' ;
$request_method = 'GET' ;
$params_a = array(
  "q" => "from:".htmlspecialchars($_POST['twitter_id']),
  "since" => "2019-08-25",
  "until" => "2019-09-01",
  "include_entities" => "true",
) ;
```

Therefore, it must be written as follows. How do I get "since_id" and "max_id"?

```
$request_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json' ;
$request_method = 'GET' ;
$params_a = array(
  "q" => "from:".htmlspecialchars($_POST['twitter_id']),
  "since_id" => "xxxx",
  "max_id" => "xxxx",
  "include_entities" => "true",
) ;
```

---

**March 23, 2020. I have added the following code and explanation.**

I know(POST reception is possible)

- "since" => "2019-08-25"
- "until" => "2019-09-01"

Don't know(POST reception is not possible)

- "since_id"
- "max_id"

The purpose of the question is how to get "since_id" and "max_id" from "2019-08-25" and "2019-09-01" (from which request destination)?  about it

---

**March 24, 2020. I have added the following code and explanation.**

I do not have the associative array below.

```
$getApiAry = array(
  "since_id" => "xxxx",
  "max_id" => "xxxx",
) ;
```

I have the following associative array.

```
$dataAry = array(
  "q" => "from:".htmlspecialchars($_POST['twitter_id']),
  "since" => "2019-08-25",
  "UNTIL" => "2019-09-01",
  "include_entities" => "true",
) ;
```

I would like to request $dataAry to the API to get $getApiAry and from there to the statuses / user_timeline using the following associative array.

```
$params_a = array(
  "q" => "from:".htmlspecialchars($_POST['twitter_id']),
  "since_id" => "xxxx",
  "max_id" => "xxxx",
  "include_entities" => "true",
) ;
```

Comment: Hello, this site is not so others can write the code you need for your project. It is to help you with the code you are attempting to use that may not be working. Please post any relevant code that you have tried and may be related to your issue or what you are attempting to do. this will help to ensure that you do not get negative votes. Best of luck!

Comment: @dalelandry I have added the code and description to the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have an associative array:

```
$params_a = array(
  "q" => "from:".htmlspecialchars($_POST['twitter_id']),
  "since_id" => "xxxx",
  "max_id" => "xxxx",
  "include_entities" => "true",
) ;
```

These have key/value pairs. Get the value by calling on the key with the name of the array like so.

```
$since_id = $params_a["since_id"];
$max_id = $params_a["max_id"];
```

Now the value of the array using that key is stored in the declared variables

```
$since_id 
$max_id
```

using a foreach loop

```
$params_a = array(
  "q" => "from:".htmlspecialchars($_POST['twitter_id']),
  "since_id" => "xxxx",
  "max_id" => "xxxx",
  "include_entities" => "true",
) ;

foreach($params_a as $key => $value){
    echo $key." => ".$value."<br>";
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
q -> from:1
since_id -> xxxx
max_id -> xxxx
include_entities -> true
```

this will parse through the array and post the key/value pairs

Now if you know the key value of the assoc array you are looking for, simply place a conditional in your loop to parse that data out only.

```
foreach($params_a as $key => $value){
  if($key === "since_id" || $key === "max_id"){
      echo $key." -> ".$value."<br>";
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
since_id -> xxxx
max_id -> xxxx
```

Comment: I have added the description to the body of the question.

Comment: I have added the description to the body of the question.I don't know "since_id" and "max_id", so I want to get them from the API first.